# Whenever I open Trash/ Partition, ubuntu kills all the processes and locks me out

Tags: 21.10

Whenever I try to open the trash or any ubuntu partition, ubuntu kills all the processes and locks me out.

It is working fine when I open /home directory.

Also, it is showing data of partition in terminal.

But when I try to opens it, it kills all processes. Same thing is happening with trash and whenever I connect a pendrive or a disk.

I have disabled the lock screen in the settings tab.

OS: Ubuntu 21.10 64 bit GNOME:40.4.0 Windowing system: Wayland

ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The 21.10 release has not been supported for almost a year. You may want to upgrade to 22.04 or 22.10 to see if the problem persists 

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I have data in my partition. That will be deleted in case i move to another version.

Comment: Why would data be deleted?  You can upgrade as per links I provided in my prior comment (inc. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades) and you can non-destructively re-install Ubuntu Desktop systems such that data isn't erased, and *manually installed* packages (*ie. those you added*) from Ubuntu repositories automatically re-install too.  If you want support for your EOL release, you'll have to use elsewhere such as SE *Unix & Linux* suggested in my prior comment (on-topic link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to 22.10 and the issue is resolved.
It was probably due to some corrupt system files.